# How to fix an error 'Undefined and error message: this.f is not a constructor' in firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase for my web app. I am using Firebase client SDK in Node.js for authentication of users in my webapp. But `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` function is throwing error with error code:

> Undefined and error message: this.f is not a constructor.

I have searched on net for these errors but couldn't find a suitable answer. I am also using express-generator in my web app.

This is my app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

const firebaseConfig = {
  Here lies the credentials
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my login.js which is used in the login route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    console.log('details', req.body);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.pass).then(function(){
      res.render('dashboard', {data: req.body});
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.`enter code here`
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log('Error code', errorCode);
      console.log('Error message', errorMessage);
    });
    
  });

module.exports = router;
```

login.ejs is a form, on submitting the form I get these errors

> [Rendered login.ejs on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy6Yx.png)
>
> error code: Undefined and error message: this.f is not a constructor
>
> [Here i am getting the values from the form but auth fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LT9A.png)

Could you please advise me on resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1906) was accidentally introduced in v6.2.1. v6.2.0 should be fine. Firebase team is working on a fix to be pushed shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug as I'm seeing it too. Reported this at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1906

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "dependencies": {
"firebase": "^5.9.0",
"firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.2.0"
      },
```

The above versions are fine to use

Comment: My firebase version is 6.2.2 and i am not using either admin or cloud functions.